# Conditional in Thymeleaf with text template mode

Tags: java, if-statement, thymeleaf

I'm trying to process the thymeleaf template with plain text which includes the conditional operator:

```
<th:block th:if = "${[(${test})] == true}"> it works </th:block>
```

but i have such output:

```
<th:block th:if = "${true == true}"> it works </th:block>
```

Could you tell me, where did i go wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using [textual template modes](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#textual-template-modes), you can't use html tags like `<th:block />` anymore.  Instead, the syntax looks like this:

```
[# th:if="${test}"]it works[/]
```

Comment: Oh, it's true. I removed html tags and now it's working. Thank you!